# Multiple Conditionals String with ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.5, conditional

I am trying to use Field Calculator to use a multiple conditional based on a string in another field of the same attribute table.

[image]

I have written the code below, but without success.

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def hazardValue( !Group! )
    if !Group! = '1.1':
        return 1
    if !Group! = '1.2':
        return 2
    if !Group! = '1.5':
        return 4        
    if !Group! = '2.1':
        return 3
    else
        return 5
```

Hazard =

```
hazardValue( !Group! )
```

It is always returning an error:

> There was a failure during processing, check the Geoprocessing Results window for details

Comment: the !Group! is out of scope for the code block. Take out the exclamation marks in the code block *only* and change the assignment equals (=) to a conditional equals (==) then it should work. You will also need a colon on the else: statement and at the start def hazardValue(Group):

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please always include error messages as text as images sometimes don't display well on some devices, and text is also searchable (to help others find similar messages).

Comment: Also your message says "check the Geoprocessing Results window" - did you do that?  The full error message will be contained in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close I think.  In an `if` statement, you need double equals `==`, and you are passing your `!Group!` in your expression into a new variable (`myfield`) in your function.

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def hazardValue(myfield):
    if myfield  == '1.1':
        return 1
    elif myfield  == '1.2':
        return 2
    elif myfield  == '1.5':
        return 4        
    elif myfield  == '2.1':
        return 3
    else:
        return 5
```

Hazard =

```
hazardValue(!Group!)
```